# WPF / XAML / MVVM - UserControl - Reusable DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, user-controls

Alright, so I've backed myself into a corner, and am probably misnaming what I'm trying to do...  That said, here's the gist:

My Goal: I'm trying to create a simple reusable DataGrid that I can implement in several areas of a MVVM based Time Card system.  This will be used to input data as well as visualize already submitted and approved time cards.  Note that the control itself isn't MVVM, as it's goal is to be a reusable control, so the View/ViewModel is tightly coupled.

My Problems:

1. The bindings aren't throwing errors, but they are also not working.  I can see rows, enter new lines, but no data is committed to my ViewModel, which implements my Model.
2. I think I confused myself on the entire binding of this control.  DataContext is there, but honestly I'm quite confused as to why it works (and why I had to jump through hoops to get some of it to work).  I understand the disassociation between the Visual Tree and the DataGridXXXColumn implementations; but I don't understand why the VM I'm implementing this control in refuses to agree with it (which is why I think problem #1 exists).
3. I've been through hundreds of posts trying to get this to work.  I thought I understood MVVM / WPF, but then this type of binding seems to be better than I am.  The day bindings below aren't hooked up on purpose; I am trying to tackle this one step at a time, and the combo boxes sounded like a good place to start (oops).
4. If I missed anything, or if you need more information, please don't hesitate to ask.

My View (UserControl)

```
<UserControl x:Class="TimeCard.UserControls.WeeklyGridView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeCard.UserControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" DataContext="{Binding}">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DgvItemSource" Source="{Binding TimeCardWeekly}"/>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Common;component/Themes/Styling.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>

    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
              HeadersVisibility="All"  AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke"
              GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DgvItemSource}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTimeCard, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue={x:Static CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder}}">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Program" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=SelectedTimeCard.ProgramNumbers, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mon" Width="Auto" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterFieldText}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tue" Width="Auto" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterFieldText}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wed" Width="Auto" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterFieldText}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Thu" Width="Auto" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterFieldText}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fri" Width="Auto" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterFieldText}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sat" Width="Auto" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterFieldText}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sun" Width="Auto" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterFieldText}" />
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Category" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=SelectedTimeCard.CategoryData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Sub Category" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=SelectedTimeCard.SubcategoryData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Explanation" Width="*">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=SelectedTimeCard.Explanation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

My ViewModel (defined in the code behind on the view, since this is a UserControl):

```
    public partial class WeeklyGridView : UserControl
{
    public WeeklyGridView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<WeeklyGridModel> TimeCardWeekly
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<WeeklyGridModel>) GetValue(TimeCardWeeklyDp);
        set => SetValue(TimeCardWeeklyDp, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeCardWeeklyDp =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TimeCardWeekly", typeof(ObservableCollection<WeeklyGridModel>),
            typeof(WeeklyGridView));

    public WeeklyGridModel SelectedTimeCard
    {
        get => (WeeklyGridModel) GetValue(SelectedTimeCardDp);
        set => SetValue(SelectedTimeCardDp, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTimeCardDp =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedTimeCard", typeof(WeeklyGridModel),
            typeof(WeeklyGridView));
}
```

My Model:

```
 public class WeeklyGridModel : BaseModel
{
    public WeeklyGridModel()
    {

    }

    private List<string> _programNumbers;

    public List<string> ProgramNumbers
    {
        get => Helpers.DummyData.ProgramData;
        set { _programNumbers = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private List<string> _categoryData;

    public List<string> CategoryData
    {
        get => Helpers.DummyData.CategoryData;
        set { _categoryData = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private List<string> _subcategoryData;

    public List<string> SubcategoryData
    {
        get => Helpers.DummyData.SubcategoryData;
        set { _subcategoryData = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private double _monday;

    public double Monday
    {
        get => _monday;
        set { _monday = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private double _tuesday;

    public double Tuesday
    {
        get => _tuesday;
        set { _tuesday = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private double _wednesday;

    public double Wednesday
    {
        get => _wednesday;
        set { _wednesday = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private double _thursday;

    public double Thursday
    {
        get => _thursday;
        set { _thursday = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private double _friday;

    public double Friday
    {
        get => _friday;
        set { _friday = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private double _saturday;

    public double Saturday
    {
        get => _saturday;
        set { _saturday = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private double _sunday;

    public double Sunday
    {
        get => _sunday;
        set { _sunday = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _explanation;

    public string Explanation
    {
        get => _explanation;
        set { _explanation = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

Expected Implementation:

```
<userControlsInternal:WeeklyGridView 
    TimeCardWeekly="{Binding TimeCardWeekly, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    SelectedTimeCard="{Binding SelectedTimeCard, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The Error on my Implementation (I get this for both attempted bindings):

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'TimeCardWeekly' property of the type 'timecard_UserControls_...'. A binding can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

How am I not binding to the Dependence Property?  Pretty sure they are defined right.

Any/all help you have is greatly appreciated. I've been screwing with this for too long now; I have to be missing some fundamental issue.

**Edit:** BaseModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged using CallerMemberName (just fyi)

Comment: the whole idea of MVVM is to **separate** Views and ViewModels. You telling that your View's code-behind is your ViewModel, but code-behind is actually a View, so you just coupled them as strong as it can be. You have to review your knowladge of MVVM. I'm also highly recommended to use some kind of MVVM framework (for example [Prism](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/), [Caliburn.Micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/) or [MVVMLight](http://www.mvvmlight.net/))

Comment: Also, your Model doesn't have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Actually, what you calling a Model (`WeeklyGridModel`) is looking more like ViewModel to me.

Comment: I don't see a problem in the code you posted. I also put it in a blank project and it seemed fine (though not actually binding to data). I could only evoke the exception if I misnamed the dependency property. When do you get the exception and does the IDE show a "pointer" to where it is happening? Does it underline the problem in the XAML at design time (or after building the project)? You seem to have adulterated the error message for brevity, but could you include the whole thing? (The string 'timecard_UserControls_...' seems strange to me because that isn't the name of your view type.)

Comment: @vasily.sib The idea of the above is a reusable control, not MVVM in this case, but to be reused in a MVVM app (I was under the impression that this implementation was allowed).  Although, I do agree that a framework in the long run would be very beneficial with the rest of the project.

Comment: @andrew the error only comes up in the designer, even after a clean/rebuild.  Run time, the code is fine outside of the fact the bindings are dead.  The only thing missing from the error message above is the full name of the control as the designer sees it, so 'TimeCard_UserControls_WeeklyGridView_12_248298088'.

Comment: @vasily.sib Also, I thought the idea behind MVVM was the VM handled the coupling between the View and the Model - the Model being only the storage medium for data.  In this case, the code above is only there to handle the structure of data I want to hold; the VM would then take this data, manipulate it however I see fit, then represent it to the user.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @Marty No, that not the case. You may read a [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) and/or [Prism docs](http://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/) to get what MVVM actually is. As I said before, the key point is a separation of concerns. ViewModels should know about Views as less as possible. They just do some preparation/aggregation/transformation logic with data aqired from Model, so it can be showed in Views and also receive data from View to prepare/aggregate/transform it and pass to Model.